# Android show custom views on home screen

Tags: android, android-widget, homescreen

Edit:
Is there a way to show/hide a textview or imageview on home screen ?

In the attached image, on top left corner is a green colored icon which on click will do some work. I am looking for something like this.

Should I use widgets for this? After spending some time googling, I think widgets are not the ones which I'm looking for. I might be wrong though. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I have done something similar.I have saved few phone numbers in my database. If i receive a call from those list i show  a custom toast. Is that you looking for?

Comment: Create  layout like this and then you can set this layout to the toast. toast.setView(layout); I hope you want to close this layout once call gets disconnected

Comment: @playmaker420 Thats a great clue. I have edited my question. Can you please go thru the question again and see whether I can still do that with the custom Toast?

Comment: You can change the visibility of the views in the layout.Im not sure about the click

Comment: I think it will work http://techblogon.com/custom-toast-android-example-with-source-code-description/ see this